# Que metodo usar para insertar de un formulario datos en array en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Como insertar, usando php, correctamente datos de un array a una base de datos en mysql, básicamente el array viene de un formulario donde el usuario puede agregar lineas segun los productos que solicita, en cada linea que agrega, esta el codigo del producto, la descripcion, la cantidad, alguna nota, yo le agrego la palabra confermata, el nombre del usuario (por sesion) y la fecha de la solicitud, puede insertar n lineas, este es un ejemplo del resultado de una solicitud.

```
Array
(
    [codice] => Array
        (
            [0] => 302
            [1] => 245
            [2] => 624
            [3] => 025
        )

    [articolo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cacio Molisano Bianco Stagionato Kg. 1,5
            [1] => Cacio rettangolare gr 1500 
            [2] => Fusilli Mediterranei 500 gr
            [3] => LATTE F.P.S. DA 1/2 LT PET
        )

    [quantita] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [stato] => Array
        (
            [0] => Confermata
            [1] => Confermata
            [2] => Confermata
            [3] => Confermata
        )

    [note] => Array
        (
            [0] => primer producto
            [1] => segundo producto
            [2] => tercer producto
            [3] => cuarto producto
        )

    [usuario] => Valter Lafratta
    [fecha] => 16/03/2020
)
```

En mysql tengo esto:

```
INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note) VALUES ($usuario,$fecha,$codice,$articolo,$quantita,$stato,$note)
```

Alguien me puede aclarar la metodología correcta para insertar el array?

**UPDATE**

Como nota adicional, las variables las toma a traves de $_POST, por ejemplo:

```
$articolo = $_POST['articolo'];
```

A excepción de la fecha y el usuario:

```
$_POST['usuario'] = $_SESSION['username'];
$_POST['fecha'] = date('d/m/Y');
```

**UPDATE 2**

A petición agrego el código para la inserción de datos:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
$_POST['usuario']   = $_SESSION['username'];
$_POST['fecha']     = date('d/m/Y');

$usuario            = $_POST['usuario'];
$fecha              = $_POST['fecha'];
$codice             = $_POST['codice'];
$articolo           = $_POST['articolo'];
$quantita           = $_POST['quantita'];
$stato              = $_POST['stato'];
$note               = $_POST['note'];

$data = array(
     'usuario'   => $usuario,
    'fecha'     => $fecha,
    'codice'    => $codice,
    'articolo'  => $articolo,
    'quantita'  => $quantita,
    'stato'     => $stato,
    'note'      => $note    

);

$ready = '';
$fail = '';

$data = array_filter($data);

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "","DB");


if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connect failed: ' . $con->connect_error;
    exit();
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );

if ( $stmt === false ) {
    echo 'prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error);
    trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$con->query("START TRANSACTION");

foreach ($data as $row) {

    $bind = $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', 
    $row[1],
    $row[2],
    $row[3], 
    $row[4], 
    $row[5], 
    $row[6], 
    $row[7]);

    if ( $bind === false ) {
        echo 'bind_param() ha fallado: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error);
    }

    $exec = $stmt->execute();

    if ( $exec === false ) {
        $fail .= sprintf("%s no se insertará porque execute() ha fallado: %s<br />", $row[0], htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    } else {
        $ready .= sprintf("%s será insertado en la base de datos.<br />", $row[0]);
    }

}
$stmt->close();
if ( ! empty( $ready ) )
    echo $ready;
if ( ! empty( $fail ) )
    echo $fail;

$commit = $con->query("COMMIT");
if ( $commit === false ) {
    echo "Transacción Commit fallida<br />";
}
echo "<br />Fin del script.<br />";
$con->close();

?>
```

La ejecución de este código me da el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Only variables can be passed by reference

**UPDATE 3**

Elimine del array a usuario y fecha, ya que los mismos no entran dentro del mismo, el resultado me arrojo el siguiente error:

> 191 no se insertará porque execute() ha fallado: Column 'articolo'
>   cannot be null Julienne vsk 3 Kg no se insertará porque execute() ha
>   fallado: Data too long for column 'codice' at row 1 1 no se insertará
>   porque execute() ha fallado: Column 'articolo' cannot be null
>   Confermata no se insertará porque execute() ha fallado: Data too long
>   for column 'codice' at row 1 Primer producto no se insertará porque
>   execute() ha fallado: Data too long for column 'codice' at row 1
>
> Fin del script.

El último resultado repite codice y articolo, no hace el recorrido por todo el array.
Agradecido de antemano.
Valter.

Comment: Deberías aclarar si es un sólo array o varios arrays y qué API usas para la conexión si `mysqli` o si `PDO`.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. El array es como se muestra en la pregunta, el usuario puede ingresar de 1 a n cantidad de productos en un solo pedido, no se si eso contesta la pregunta de un array o varios arrays. Con respecto a la conexión, mysqli, de la cual tengo una gran duda y es por eso que hago la pregunta en la pagina, debo usar bind_param, es un insert normal a la base de datos, hay otro metodo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías usar `bind_param` para evitar *Inyección SQL*, que es un grave riesgo de seguridad. Sugiero que intentes con `bind_param` y si no te funciona nos dices y te ayudaremos.

Comment: Te has liado un poco en tu código sin necesidad. Déjame hacer unas pruebas para simplificar...

Comment: vale muy agradecido @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu array los datos vienen por partes, entonces no es tan simple *alinearlos*  para que la consulta asuma cada valor de cada columna de cada sub-array en una fila.

Aparte de eso, estamos ante un array no uniforme porque el `usuario` va a su aire.

Mediante este código se puede organizar el array para luego dinamizar la inserción. De todos modos, convendría que te plantees (si puedes) organizar de otro modo el código en la fuente que manda esos datos, para que te los mande con una estructura acorde a lo que necesitas.

Este es el código que propongo. No voy a trabajar en insertarlo en tu contexto, creo que podrás hacer sin mucha dificultad. Es una buena idea meterlo en un contexto de transacciones, como se ve en tu intento.

Solamente te dejo lo básico, que es tratar a `$_POST`, para organizar los datos y luego armar la preparación de la consulta y su binding con los datos.

He puesto una consulta literal para probar que debería funcionar, si lo incorporas bien.

```
#Para sacar los datos del usuario aparte
$usuario=array();
#Quitamos los datos del usario para poder combinar los otros datos
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){
    if (!is_array($v)){
        unset ($_POST[$k]);
        $usuario[$k]=$v;
    }
}

#Aquí combinamos los datos de cada array particular
#para armar una fila completa de valores
$rows=array_map(function(){return func_get_args();},...array_values($_POST));
//echo implode(",",$usuario);
$types="sssssss";
foreach ($rows as $row){
    #Combinamos los datos del usuario, con los de cada fila
    $params=array_merge($usuario,$row);
    #Sólo para probar la consulta... borrar
        $forTest="INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (".implode(',',$params).")";
        echo $forTest.PHP_EOL;
    
    #Consulta preparada
    $sql="INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";    

    #Desde la versión 5.6+ PHP permite usar ...$params
    #en versiones anteriores hay que recurrir a call_user_func
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    if(!$stmt->excute()){
        #Sólo para debug, no dejes esta línea con mensajes internos
        echo $con->error;
    }    
}
```

---

### Observación

Si la columna `fecha` es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`, debes convertir el valor de `fecha` que hay en el $_POST  a un formato `YYYY/MM/DD`. Eso lo puedes hacer en la parte donde se asigna `$usuarios` y se hace el `unset`.

---

La salida de la variable de prueba `$forTest` es esta:

```
INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (Valter Lafratta,16/03/2020,302,Cacio Molisano Bianco Stagionato Kg. 1,5,1,Confermata,primer producto)
INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (Valter Lafratta,16/03/2020,245,Cacio rettangolare gr 1500,2,Confermata,segundo producto)
INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (Valter Lafratta,16/03/2020,624,Fusilli Mediterranei 500 gr,3,Confermata,tercer producto)
INSERT INTO spesa (usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, stato, note)
    VALUES (Valter Lafratta,16/03/2020,21,LATTE F.P.S. DA 1/2 LT PET,4,Confermata,cuarto producto)
```

Comment: Gracias, no lo he podido probar todavia, se me ha caido la conexion al servidor, estoy desde casa, mañana en la oficina hago las pruebas y te hago saber, de verdad muy agradecido por tu tiempo y consideración, un abrazo desde Italia.

Comment: De nada @Valter y mucho ánimo con el Coronavirus. Estoy confinado aquí en España por la misma situación. Saludos.

Comment: He probado el código y no inserta la data en la base de datos. Me arroja el siguiente error: **Cannot unpack array with string keys**. A tu propuesta le agregue la siguiente información: `$_POST['usuario']   = $_SESSION['username'];` `$_POST['fecha']  = date('d/m/Y');` `$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];`
`$fecha  = $_POST['fecha'];` Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @Valter OK, el error es porque estamos creando el sub-array con los datos del usuario con índices string. Debería resolverse si en la parte donde creas `$usuario` (primer `foreach`) cambias esto: `$usuario[$k]=$v;` por esto: **`$usuario[]=$v;`** así `$params` será un array con todos los índices numéricos, y funcionará.

Comment: Excelente, muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu dedicación, el código funciono perfecto. Un fuerte abrazo. Valter.

Comment: @Valter me alegra de que se haya resuelto. Saludos.